# Error in url mapping in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/tasker")
    public class TaskerController 
   {
    @Autowired
    private TaskerService taskService;


    @RequestMapping(value ="/tasker_logout")
    public String logoutform(TaskerPojo task,HttpSession hs) 
    {

        hs.invalidate();
        System.out.println("in logout form " + task);
        return "tasker_logout";

    }
```

In my other file when i use the `"<a href="tasker/tasker_logout"></a>"`the   url is automatically changed to 
http://localhost:9090/TaskBuddy/tasker/tasker/tasker_logout.

But If i use the `"<a href="/tasker_logout"></a>"` it maps it like
"http://localhost:9090/tasker_logout"

Comment: did you try `"<a href="tasker_logout"></a>"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You application context might be running under "/tasker" hence why your url is mapped as

```
<a href="tasker/tasker/tasker_logout/>
```

1. First tasker/ - application context
2. Second tasker/ - your overall controller mapping
3. Third tasker_logout - your mapping for the method

Ensure your application context is running on /* and not /tasker and you shall be fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Show us how you configured your application context and show us how the working links are rendered

Comment: I am using two controller one tasker and other customer.

Comment: Show me the code so we can figure it out. Don't know how its all setup currently for your working controllers and your application context